# fabric connection via gateway not working

Tags: ssh, fabric

I'm trying to run fabric through a gateway but am having difficulty: fabric reports a timeout trying to connect to the destination host.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/network.py", line 452, in connect
    raise NetworkError(msg, e)
fabric.exceptions.NetworkError: Timed out trying to connect to 10.31.219.57 (tried 1 time)
```

I use the `--gateway=dmzhost` on the command-line but cannot confirm if it is actually using that gateway or not. I have checked that I can connect to the gateway with ssh normally, and then further to the target machine with the IP givne to fabric.

Any ideas on what may be wrong or is there a way to get more debug information as to what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Fabric defect which ignored the gateway. It has been fixed in 1.5.1.